# Simplify Git bash CLI steps to commit the code to Github

Tags: vs-code, git

I Would like simplify the below steps to commit code to Github. Please share any suggestions

Step to Commit and Push code from local folder to repository through terminal.

1. Move to Full retrieve file path
                   cd /d/FullRetrieveFile/force-app/main/default
                   cd classes/
2. Copy new class to repository cloned folder 
                   cp  -r  testvsdemoclass.cls  /d/ClonedFolder/retrieveUnpackaged/classes
3. Move to repository cloned folder
                   cd /d/ClonedFolder
4. Add, Commit and Push the code to repository
                   git add -A 
                   git commit -m "new calss" 
                   git push

Comment: why are those steps necessary? Why can't the user work directly with the file in their repository cloned folder and then commit and push any local changes that git will be tracking in the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

**The steps to commit code to Github are already simplified with git. You should be doing your work directly in the cloned repository folder through your IDE.**

I'd suggest looking through some documentation on [Git workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows)

The reason to work in the cloned repository folder is to have **Git tracking all your changes**. You can commit whichever changes you want by simply clicking "commit" on the IDE (Intellij, for example) or using git add/git commit/git stage depending on the IDE.

If there's changes that become irrelevant, you can discard them and continue on your way. There's no need to have your work done outside of the git clone repository and then create some script to move it into the local repository and commit it - that's creating work for no benefit.

The major point with git is to let/have **git track the changes** that occur for you and then allow you to control which of those changes should be **committed** and ultimately which commits should be **pushed** to your remote repository (in this case, Github).